# iOS NSDateFormatter unable to parse the hour properly

Tags: ios, datetime, nsdateformatter

First the code:

```
NSString* dateTimeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [aDictionary objectForKey:@"date"], [aDictionary objectForKey:@"time"]];

NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];    
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddHHmm"];

NSDate* dsate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateTimeString];
```

dateTimeString string value is "201106242204"

however the dsdate gets incorrect value, in the debugger it shows: 2011-06-24 19:04:00 +0000

as you can see the hour should be 22 not 19. I have already wasted quite q bit of time on this. Tried setting the time zone, locale etc etc but nothing has any effect.

Comment: Try changing your device's timezone settings and see if the date's hour changes. That'll at least tell you if this is a time zone issue or not.

Comment: The time zone on the development mac was set to UK and that did have an effect on the date returned by NSDateFormatter. So how should I take into account this ugliness ?

Comment: I would take RyanR's suggestion. It looks like if you don't specify the timezone in the setFormat string, it does not default to the local time zone. You can try using the zone format patterns to get the time zone in: http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-4.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: Ok I now added the time zone to the string, so the changes are:
1. [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@ EET"
2. [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddHHmm zzz"];

however, this still doesn't solve this issue. However the difference in hours seems to have been decreased by 1.

Comment: Aren't you in EEST right now? And just FYI, if you hardcode the timezone in that string, it's going to break for anyone outside of that timezone. You should pass the timezone in from where ever your date/time is coming from.

Comment: Apparently iOS doesnt recognize EEST it only knows about EET, and EET takes into account daylight savings etc. Also my app is only supposed to work in a country located in the EET. So for me it doesn't matter. Any ways I solved the problem using the NSTimeZone magic which I have poste below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be aware that [NSDateFormatter is locale-aware](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html). This means that even if you specify a date format string, if the current locale on a device has a different format for the string you give it, it will override the string you provided the formatter. What is your UTC offset at your present location? Because NSDateFormatter always gives UTC time, if your offset is -6, it is giving you back the correct value, just in a different timezone. One of the features of NSDateFormatter I really don't like. You *might* get the result you want by calling setTimeZone: on the date formatter.

Try calling [-descriptionWithCalendarFormat:timeZone:locale:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html%3a) on the parsed NSDate instance, passing your locale and timezone. I'm curious if it outputs your desired result.

Comment: I am at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finland +3 in summer, +2 otherwise. I also tried this: [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:60*60*3]]; But doesn't help.

Comment: I'm confused - your debugger output shows 19:04, but your state the hour shows '16'. From looking at the debugger output, it definitely appears to be a timezone difference, as 22:04 in your local time zone is 19:04 in UTC. Have you tried passing the timezone offset as part of your date string?

Comment: Sorry about 16, that was a typo, should be 19. How can I pass tz offer in the date string ?

Comment: Use [this](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns) for timezone formatting

Answer (score 1):

So finally I solved this. How:

```
NSString* dateTimeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [aDictionary objectForKey:@"date"], [aDictionary objectForKey:@"time"]];

NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
NSTimeZone* normalTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"EET"];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddHHmm"];

NSDate* date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateTimeString];
NSDate* correctedDate = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:[normalTimeZone secondsFromGMT]];
```

I think Cocoa or iOS should have at least an API which doest try to act smart.